# How variables save non-scalar data

Tags: php, file, variables, memory, memory-management

I am a bit confused as to how variables store data of a text file into memory.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<?php
$varContent  = 'book.txt';
```

Now, what I would like to clear out is that, what gets stored in `$varContent`? is the the simple string name `'book.txt'` or does the file type, header, information inside the file gets stored in the variable?

And what the negative sides (if any) of storing a files entire content with a variable, does it break some convention or is it completely acceptable?

To further clarify my point, if I indeed stored a file destination as shown above to a variable, and I used this variable all over inside my class, is there some sort of memory constraint or performance problem? Because, I am under the impression that assigning string/int to a variable is fine because, the memory footprint is small, but calling here and there, a 5MB .txt file may not.

So, I'm just tying to understand this a little better. 
thanks.

Comment: That is just a string `book.txt` 8 bytes of data.  You would need to read the file into a var to get the contents.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have shown the only thing that gets stored is the simple string. There's no additional information to indicate to PHP the string refers to a file.

**EDIT**

To open a file and have metadata in memory, use something like [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php).

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject("/etc/passwd");
$stat = $file->fstat();
```

Comment: What about using the method Martin shows, if I were to get all the makeup of the file, and store is inside a variable, and do some intricate things, does that slow the memory down.

Comment: That will store only the contents of the file in memory. There is no extra storage for file metadata. If you're interested in something like that take a look at [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) et al. Those objects will take more memory, but they do offer the metadata your asking about.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a string. If you want to load a file, you can use

```
$content = file_get_contents("book.txt");
```

(And you will get only the content, no additional information).

Comment: What additional information is there, aside from the content?

Comment: Things like file owner, group, modification time, some permissions - it depends on the operating system you use.